# Вылетает ошибка debug assertion failed при записи данных в файл

Tags: c

Вот код:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MY_LAB_H
#define MY_LAB_H
struct polinom {
    int n;
    float *P;
};
void read_file(FILE *f1, struct polinom *p);
void dif(struct polinom *p);
void dif_k(struct polinom *p, int k);
void out_pol(struct polinom *p);
void write_file(FILE *f1, struct polinom *p);
#endif
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "my_lab.h"
void read_file(FILE *f1, struct polinom *p) {
    /*FILE *f1;
    f1 = fopen("my_lab.txt", "rt");
    if (f1 == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }*/
    fscanf_s(f1, "%d", &(p->n));
    p->P = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*(p->n) + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < (p->n) + 1; i++) {
        fscanf_s(f1, "%f ", &((p->P)[i]));
    }
    fclose(f1);
}
void dif(struct polinom *p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (p->n) + 1; i++) {
        *(p->P + i) = *(p->P + i)*((p->n) - i);
    }
}
void dif_k(struct polinom *p,int k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        dif(p);
    }
}
void out_pol(struct polinom *p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (p->n) + 1; i++) {
        printf("%f ", *((p->P) + i));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void write_file(FILE *f1, struct polinom *p) {
    /*FILE *f1;
    f1 = fopen("my_lab.txt", "wt");
    if (f1 == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }*/
    /*fprintf(f1, "%d\n", p->n);*/
    for (int i = 0; i < p->n + 1; i++) {
        fprintf(f1, "%f ", (p->P)[i]);
    }
    fprintf(f1, "\n");
    fclose(f1);
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "my_lab.h"
int main() {
    struct polinom p = { 0,0 };
    FILE *f1;
    f1 = fopen("my_lab.txt", "rt");
    if (f1 == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        int k;
        printf("Input k:\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &k);
        read_file(f1, &p);
        dif(&p);
        dif_k(&p, k);
        out_pol(&p);
        write_file(f1, &p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А конкретнее? Сообщение полностью, что вводится/выводится, etc etc...

Comment: Вы открыли файл на чтение f1 = fopen("my_lab.txt", "rt"); а потом закрыли в `read_file()`- Вы реально в него так хотите записать что-то? PS: чтобы не вводить в заблуждение себя и других - лучше закрывайте файл в той же функции, где его открываете. Иначе можете потом очень долго искать проблемы.